# How to incorporate $ in a given expression?

Tags: haskell

I want to write an expression which will give a list that is equal to the list comprehension `` [x|x<-[1..100], x`mod`7==0] ``, but I'm asked by my teacher to use `$` in this program.

So, how could I use `$` in here?

PS: I'm new to Haskell, so would prefer easy expressions, please.

Comment: That's are strange task... for _any_ expression `e`, you can always obtain an equivalent expression `id $ e`. That's certainly not the intended answer, but dumb questions demand dumb answers IMO...  — Did your teacher also say anything to the end like “_without_ a list comprehension”?

Answer (score 2):

`($)` is in an infix operator with a type signature

`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`

which means it takes two parameters, first a function `(a -> b)` (on the left) which accepts a single parameter, a value of type designated by the type variable `a`. The second parameter of `($)` (on the right) is a single value again designated by the type variable `a`. Then the `($)` operator simply applies it's second parameter to the first parameter. So for an example `(+2) $ 3` would give us `5`.

So if you insist on doing list comprehensions you may do as follows in point-free style;

```
Prelude> [x|x<-[1..100], (== 0) . mod x $ 7]
[7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98]
```

or in a more straightforward fashion

```
Prelude> filter ((==0) . (`mod` 7)) $ take 100 [1..]
[7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98]
```

Answer (score 1):

$ just means "take whatever is on the right, and pass it as argument to the left".
So for example :

```
map (`mod`7) (take 100 [1..])
map (`mod`7) $ take 100 [1..]
```

Those two lines are the same, the $ just means you can avoid the parenthesis around the second call.
The take is useless but I didn't have a better idea for a simple example :)

Comment: You may want to point out that the expressions you provide are not equivalent to the OP list comprehension. Or make them equivalent.